# How do I add DIVs to the Jquery - Simpleslider plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [Jquery-SimpleSlider](https://github.com/amitsankhe/Jquery-SimpleSlider) to make a lightbox out of a group of images each with its respective description. 
As you can see in [this demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Facebook-Like-jQuery-Image-Gallery-Lightbox-Plugin-AM2-Simple-Slider/) the box has a white space for the description next to the image,
 i want to add html code (a bunch of divs to add a title, a descriptiom, price etc) in there instead of the description thats already there but i can't figure out how to do it.
I've tried a couple of things but no success

Here is the relevant html

```
<ul class="product-gallery">
    <li class="gallery-img">
        <img src='uploads/img1.jpg' alt="img01">
        <div data-desc="Image Descript 1"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery-img" style="display: none;">
        <img src='uploads/img2.jpg' alt="img02">
        <div data-desc="Image Descript 2"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery-img" style="display: none;">
        <img src='uploads/img3.jpg' alt="img03">
        <div data-desc="Image Descript 3"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery-img" style="display: none;">
        <img src='uploads/img4.jpg' alt="img04">
        <div data-desc="Image Descript 4"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the div containing the text that appears next to the image, but it's inside an attribute so I can't put html in it, or can i?

```
<div data-desc="Image Descript 4"></div>
```

Here is the Simpleslide js file

```
(function ($) {

jQuery.fn.Am2_SimpleSlider = function () {
    //popup div
    $div = $('<div class="product-gallery-popup"> <div class="popup-overlay"></div> <div class="product-popup-content"> <div class="product-image"> <img id="gallery-img" src="" alt="" /> <div class="gallery-nav-btns"> <a id="nav-btn-next" class="nav-btn next" ></a> <a id="nav-btn-prev" class="nav-btn prev" ></a></div> </div><div class="product-information"> <p class="product-desc"></p> </div> <div class="clear"></div><a href="#" class="cross">X</a></div></div>').appendTo('body');

    //on image click   
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.product-gallery-popup').fadeIn(500);
        $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' });
        $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($(this).find('div').attr('data-desc'));
        $Current = $(this);
        $PreviousElm = $(this).prev();
        $nextElm = $(this).next();
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
    });
    //on Next click
    $('.next').click(function () {
        $NewCurrent = $nextElm;
        $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
        $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
        $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);



        $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('div').attr('data-desc'));
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
    });
    //on Prev click
    $('.prev').click(function () {
        $NewCurrent = $PreviousElm;
        $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
        $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
        $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

        $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('div').attr('data-desc'));
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
    });
    //Close Popup
    $('.cross,.popup-overlay').click(function () {
        $('.product-gallery-popup').fadeOut(500);
        $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'initial' });
    });

    //Key Events
    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Close popup on esc
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { $('.product-gallery-popup').fadeOut(500); $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'initial' }); }
        //Next Img On Right Arrow Click
        if (e.keyCode === 39) { NextProduct(); }
        //Prev Img on Left Arrow Click
        if (e.keyCode === 37) { PrevProduct(); }
    });

    function NextProduct() {
        if ($nextElm.length === 1) {
            $NewCurrent = $nextElm;
            $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
            $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
            $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

            $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('div').attr('data-desc'));
            if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
            if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        }

    }

    function PrevProduct() {
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 1) {
            $NewCurrent = $PreviousElm;
            $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
            $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
            $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

            $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('div').attr('data-desc'));
            if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
            if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        }

    }
};

} (jQuery));
```

I have also tried changing the pop up `div($div)` in the JS file (line 5) adding another 'p' element next to the already existing 'p' element that has the description in it and added another div in the html file with `data-title="title"` in it instead of `data-desc="......"`. I also added this line:

```
$('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($(this).find('div').attr('data-desc'));
```

inside `//onimageclick` replacing `data-desc` with `data-title` but it didn't work either

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the code you have this line:

```
$('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($(this).find('div').attr('data-desc'));
```

Why don't just edit this line and use the DIV element content instead of the data-desc attribute? It would be like

```
$('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($(this).find('div').html());
```

If you are concerned about the div content being shown you can hide it by CSS